# WebRTC select camera to send

Tags: javascript, camera, webrtc, getusermedia

Let's say I have multiple video devices on my system.

1. How do I tell `getUserMedia` to select a correct camera?
2. Is there a way that I can get a list of available cameras from the WebRTC API?