# What constraints should I pass to getUserMedia() in order to get two video mediaStreamTracks?

Tags: constraints, webrtc, getusermedia

I can get mediaDevices of 'videoinput' kind via `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` promise.

I can get mediaStream via `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)` promise.

**What should `constraints` look like in order to have two video tracks in userMedia?**

Comment: What do you mean "in userMedia"? Are you trying to get two cameras at once, or are you trying to limit the possible choices down to two cameras (including what's shown in the permission prompt that some browsers implement) when `getUserMedia` is called?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get max one video track and one audio track each time you call `getUserMedia()`, but you can call it multiple times. This may ask the user more than once though, depending on https, browser, and what the user does.

Following [the standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) (which at this time requires using [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/blob/master/adapter.js) in Chrome), to get a specific "videoinput" device, pass its `deviceId` into `getUserMedia` using the `deviceId` constraint:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then(devices => {
  var camera = devices.find(device => device.kind == "videoinput");
  if (camera) {
    var constraints = { deviceId: { exact: camera.deviceId } };
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: constraints });
  }
})
.then(stream => video.srcObject = stream)
.catch(e => console.error(e));
```

The `exact` keyword makes the constraint required, guaranteeing it'll return only the right one, or fail.

If you want two cameras, you'll have to call `getUserMedia` again with a different `deviceId`, and hope the OS you're on supports it (e.g. phones generally don't).

Comment: Thank you! But we still can switch from back to front camera on phones, right?

Comment: Yes, provided you `.stop()` existing tracks before calling `getUserMedia` again. You can use either `enumerateDevices` or the `facingMode` constraint for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32364912/918910