# How to detect and change Audio Input Device in Javascript while the app is running?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I am creating speech to text web application. I want to use default system Audio Input device as microphone. I want to provide a feature which is user can change Microphones while the application is running. I am able to detect the list of audio and input devices connected but not able to change the Audio Input Device. Can anyone provide a way to implement this functionality?

Comment: See [What constraints should I pass to getUserMedia() in order to get two video mediaStreamTracks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761770/what-constraints-should-i-pass-to-getusermedia-in-order-to-get-two-video-media)

Comment: The above link which you have provided is to set a particular device from a list of devices. This is my second task. Firstly, I want to use a default device of system from a list of Audio Input Devices.

Comment: The list should contain all of the audio input devices.

Comment: Thanks @guest271314 for your suggestions. It worked for me