# Accessing audio input with getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, electron, getusermedia

I have an Electron application with React plugged for my view layer.

I want to be able to access audio input to my laptop. Audio input will be more than a microphone, I am wanting to input music into my laptop via USB as it doesn't have any audio input ports and ideally I want this to work on any laptop.

I have played around with the `getUserMedia()` api like so:

```
window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(stream => this.handleStream(stream))
      .catch(err => this.handleError(err))
```

but believe this is for accessing microphone? Is there a way you can select audio input and if so, will I be able to get an audio input from a USB device or is the `getUserMedia` API limited to microphones?

Comment: Microphone is a form of audio input. On most systems it's the only audio input configured. You enumerate audio input devices using [`navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices), then use [`deviceId`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770656/918910) to select a specific one.

Comment: That seems to be what I was looking for. If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark complete. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microphone is a form of audio input. On most systems it's the only audio input configured.

You enumerate audio input devices using [navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices), then use the [deviceId](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770656/918910) constraint with `getUserMedia` to select a specific one.

Comment: Hi @Stretch0 ! Can you confirm that `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices` can help `getUserMedia` access others audio input source (for example line-in audio from phone, CD player, mp3 player...) other than microphone as default?