# Force getUserMedia re-prompt when using HTTPS on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, webcam, navigator

I am making a simple app with two webcams that needs to work only on latest Firefox. Locally it works fine:

- the user is prompted for the access to the camera
- the user selects one camera
- the user is prompted again
- the user selects the second camera
- both streams work fine

However, when I upload it to the server which serves the page through HTTPS, the access from the first camera is remembered and I just get two of the same streams.

Is there a way to force re-prompting on HTTPS so that the user can select the other camera, as well?

This is my code:

```
    function handleSuccess1(stream) {
      video1.srcObject = stream;

      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
        then(handleSuccess2).catch(handleError);
    }

    function handleSuccess2(stream) {
      // this gets called automatically with the first stream
      // without re-prompting the user
      video2.srcObject = stream;
    }

    const constraints = {
      video: true
    };

    function handleError(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
        then(handleSuccess1).catch(handleError);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` to list the available cameras and/or microphones.

You can read about it in more detail here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices

Comment: If I got it right, then I can use the device IDs as constraints in `getUserMedia`?

Comment: Yes, pass `deviceId` into `getUserMedia` like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770656