# How to open back camera instead of front camera in Android Chrome browser in peerjs project

Tags: camera, webrtc, peerjs

I am developing a webrtc project with peerjs. when the project is opened in Android Chrome Browser, I want to use back camera. I don't find information about this feature. How can I proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetUserMedia - facingmode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086122/getusermedia-facingmode)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience with peerjs but with "vanilla" WebRTC you can pass `constraints` to `getUserMedia` for example:

> To require the rear camera, use:
>   { audio: true, video: { facingMode: { exact: "environment" } } }

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

This documentation is for Firefox, but on the bottom of the page it says:

> Chrome uses an outdated constraint syntax, but the syntax described here is available through the [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfill.