# Select camera on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, three.js, webrtc, getusermedia

I came across several questions on this subject. I'm trying to select the rear camera on an Android device running Chrome.

So, after some reading :

```
var selector = document.getElementById('video-source-selector');
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(function(devices) {
    var videoDevices = devices.map(function (item) {
      if(item.kind === 'videoinput'){
        return item;
      }
    }).filter(function( element ) {
       return element !== undefined;
    });
    var max = videoDevices.length;
    videoDevices.forEach(function(device, i) {
      var html = '';
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      if(i === max-1){ // last element reached
        html += '<option value="'+device.deviceId+'" selected>'+ device.label +'</option>';
      }
      else {
        html += '<option value="'+device.deviceId+'">'+ device.label +'</option>';
      }
      div.innerHTML = html;
      selector.appendChild(div.childNodes[0]);

      console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +
        " id = " + device.deviceId);
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
  });
  selector.addEventListener("change", function(){
    console.log(selector.value); // Works as supposed : returns the ID of the selected device
  });
```

Then, as I'm using Three.js in this app, I'm binding this ID to Jerome Etienne three extension WebcamGrabbing (https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.webar):

```
var videoGrabbing = new THREEx.WebcamGrabbing(selector.value);
```

Then I had to modify `THREEx.WebcamGrabbing` class this way (I removed the irrelevant parts):

```
THREEx.WebcamGrabbing = function(sourceDeviceId){

    ...

    console.log('webcamgrabbing : ', sourceDeviceId); // returns the expected ID

    var constraints = {
            video: {
              optional: [{
                sourceId: sourceDeviceId
              }]
            }
    }


    // try to get user media
    navigator.getUserMedia( constraints, function(stream){
            domElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }, function(error) {
            console.error("Cant getUserMedia()! due to ", error);
    });


    ...
}
```

But still, Chrome on Android is still giving me the stream of the face camera, whatever device I select...

What do I miss?

EDIT : Based on this topic ([GetUserMedia - facingmode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086122/getusermedia-facingmode)), I came up with some logs to see what's happening here :

```
   var constraints = {
            audio: false,
            video: { facingMode: { exact: "environment" } }
    }

    console.log('Try to get stream with constraints:', constraints);

    navigator.getUserMedia( constraints, function(stream){
            var videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();

            console.log('Got stream with constraints:', constraints);  // Ok
            console.log('Using video device: ' + videoTracks[0].label);  // > Using video device: camera 0, facing back

            for(var i = 0; i < videoTracks.length; i++){
              console.log('Found video device with contraints : ', videoTracks[i].label); // Found video device with contraints :  camera 0, facing back
            }

            domElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }, function(error) {
            console.error("Cant getUserMedia()! due to ", error);
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetUserMedia - facingmode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086122/getusermedia-facingmode)

Comment: @jib Also tried the way provided in this topic, but it keeps selecting the front cam.

Comment: Did you try the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2oe36eL/) in the other answer? Worked in Chrome on my S4. - Also, your own logs suggest you got the back camera: `Using video device: camera 0, facing back`.

Comment: It works well on my device too. That's why I don't see any reason that my code is still selecting the front cam, as I practically copy/pasted the fiddle?

Comment: The important bit in the other answer is that `facingMode` support in Chrome for Android is provided by the [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfill. Did you copy that?

Comment: @jib Yes, I'm calling (for test purpose) `<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>`

Comment: Then I don't know. All code shown looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to select the back camera on chrome is to use the  enumerateDevices method.

First get all the video input id's:

```
   navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function(devices) {
     devices.forEach(function(device) {

  if(device.kind=="videoinput"){
     //If device is a video input add to array.
  }
});
```

Then the first element of the array will contain the id of the front camera, the second element will contain the id of the back camera.

Finally put the id of the camera that you want to use

```
 navigator.getUserMedia({audio: false, video:  { sourceId: VideoId } }, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: I used that method in my first attempt (first code in the question): I got the right ID (back camera), but I got the stream of the front cam...

Comment: You have to make sure that only one camera stream is active, if the front camera stream is active, then you need to stop it before starting the rear camera.

Comment: Just a thought, you have made the video source id as optional, maybe you could try    video:  { sourceId: VideoId }
It works for me on chrome on android.

Comment: Those two things could help me a lot. I will try it tomorrow and tell you.

Comment: I tried  {sourceId: VideoId }, where `VideoId` is the good ID (`label` = "camera facing back"). Still the same, I just get the video stream from front cam...