# How do I select which camera lens to use when using back-camera in ngx-scanner?

Tags: angular, zxing

I am using [zxing-js/ngx-scanner](https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner) for scanning in my Angular application. In Samsung phones, the scanner scans using the wide angel lens which creates an issue in scanning.

I need to be able to allow users to choose between different lenses available or force the scanner component to use the normal lens in order to scan successfully.

So far I have tried [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59636464/how-to-select-proper-backfacing-camera-in-javascript) and [this github answer](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/619). I was trying to see if I can atleast get to choose the lens via JS. So far I haven't found any working solution.

Can someone please help with the same?