# Angular 2 and instantiation of a camera stream with html 5 video

Tags: angular, typescript, html5-video

I'm new to Angular 2.

If I have a video tag, like :

```
<video width="480" height="480" autoplay></video>
```

And a javascript example snippet to open the camera stream :

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.play();
  });
}
```

In Angular 2 + Typescript I suppose I can access the video tag like :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'video-component',
  template: `
    <video #videoplayer autoplay></video>
  `
})
export class Video {
 @ViewChild('videoplayer') videoPlayer;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let video = document.getElementById('video');

    // How to access the mediadevice ??

  }
}
```

How can I access the media device and instantiate the stream like illustrated in the javascript snippet ?

Comment: Seriously, noone ? Am I totally off with my approach here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your template you can include the video directive like this:

```
<video #video width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
```

then in your component:

```
@ViewChild('video') video:any; 
// note that "#video" is the name of the template variable in the video element

ngAfterViewInit() {
  let _video=this.video.nativeElement;
  if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                          .then(stream => {
                            _video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                            _video.play();
                          })
  }
}
```

see this on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/live-video

Comment: @DavidD. i've had some issues with plumker also, so i've uploaded a version to stackblitz.com. Hope it's helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. in macOS, works on Firefox and Safari, but not on Chrome, with `Could not start video source (NotReadableError:undefined)`

Comment: could not play your issue yet, even trying to open the camera in multiple apps. will come back if can reproduce and found a solution.

Comment: problem solved, it was just an issue at OS level on macOS. I had to go to security and allow Chrome to access camera and mic first.

Comment: Great @DavidD. glad to hear that.

Comment: Is there a way to provide an external URL to feed video stream from this approach?