# GetUserMedia - facingMode not recognized despite adapter.js

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, webrtc, getusermedia, mediastream

I want to get the video stream of my rear camera in an Ionic Application.
For this, I use getUserMedia that work correctly for the front camera.

When I change the facing mode to 'environment' I got this error :

`Unknown constraint named facingMode rejected
ConstraintNotSatisfiedError`

In my Ionic application I have already installed the npm package "webrtc-adapter".

Here is my code to get the stream from the rear camera :

```
this.constraints = { audio: true, video: {mandatory: { facingMode: 'environment'}}};
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestRuntimePermission( (status) => {
            if (cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED){

                navigator.getUserMedia(this.constraints, (stream) => {
                    let video = <HTMLVideoElement>document.getElementById('localVideo');
                    video.srcObject =  stream;
                }, function(err){
                    console.log("Error get stream: ", err.name);
                });
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.error("Error during runtime permission :", error);
        }, cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission.CAMERA);
```

I think that is a compatibility issue. Anyone can help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're using an outdated non-standard constraints syntax. [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfills the spec, so to benefit from it you have to [follow the spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28911694/918910).
E.g. instead of:

```
{audio: true, video: {mandatory: {facingMode: 'environment'}}};
```

use

```
{audio: true, video: {facingMode: {exact: 'environment'}}};
```

I already have [an answer with a working example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32364912/918910). It should work with Chrome. Not sure if this will work with ionic or not. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I use this syntax, I have no error but the camera still in the 'user' mode

Comment: @DamienLD Make sure you've updated to the [latest version](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/pull/495) of adapter. Also, what device is this on, and [what cameras](http://jsfiddle.net/jib1/tsa6rrt7/) does it have?

Comment: I have the last version of adapter (3.3.3) and I run the code on two devices : Huawei Honor and Huawei P9 lite.
I have two cameras on each but `d.label` return nothing, is it a problem ?

Comment: After many research, I found that I miss a permission to use `mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` . Do you know which permission should I add ?

Comment: Finally I decided to don't use facingMode. In my case, I have create a button to switch between each camera of the device. For this, I use `mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` to get all available cameras.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: @DamienLD If you don't have camera or microphone permission then `d.label` will be empty. But [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jib1/tsa6rrt7/) asks for camera permission first, so assuming you granted that it should show labels. You don't have to grant persistent permission.