# Webrtc rear camera not working in IOS 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, webrtc, getusermedia

Below is my code that work fine in android and ios 11 with front camera while when i use rear camera it gives error

**below works**

```
video: { width: 400, height: 200, facingMode: "user"  }
```

**Below not works**

```
video: { width: 400, height: 200, facingMode: "environment"  }
```

**Complete code**

**

```
var constraints = window.constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: { width: 400, height: 200, facingMode: "environment"  }
};
function handleSuccess(stream) {
  var videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
  console.log('Got stream with constraints:', constraints);
  console.log('Using video device: ' + videoTracks[0].label);
  stream.oninactive = function() {
    console.log('Stream inactive');
  };
  window.stream = stream; // make variable available to browser console
  video.srcObject = stream;
}
function handleError(error) {
  if (error.name === 'ConstraintNotSatisfiedError') {
    errorMsg('The resolution ' + constraints.video.width.exact + 'x' +
        constraints.video.width.exact + ' px is not supported by your device.');
  } else if (error.name === 'PermissionDeniedError') {
    errorMsg('Permissions have not been granted to use your camera and ' +
      'microphone, you need to allow the page access to your devices in ' +
      'order for the demo to work.');
  }
  errorMsg('getUserMedia error: ' + error.name, error);
}
function errorMsg(msg, error) {
  errorElement.innerHTML += '<p>' + msg + '</p>';
  if (typeof error !== 'undefined') {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
    then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
```

**

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43515300/1971013) help? (I'd try the most standard settings, so `audio: true`. Probably not the issue, but just to make sure.)

Comment: i tried even audio true not works in my ios 11

Answer (score 3):

As for now, `getUserMedia` under Apple's iOS11  **do not support `width` and `height` constrains.**

The only way to use the back camera is passing the following constraints:

```
var constraints = window.constraints = {
   audio: false,
   video: { facingMode: 'environment' }
 };
```

I have opened a bug in Apple for this, but it was closed as a duplicate.
Keep an open eye for updates from Apple regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To access rear camera on Safari Iphone, using getUserMedia, you need to set in Safari access settings **permanent access** to the camera. The "always ask" is not enought.

(I assumed, you application is served over HTTPS - which is requested for getUserMedia to work at all).