# Which media device is WebRTC using

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Following this question [How to choose input video device for webrtc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610945/how-to-choose-input-video-device-for-webrtc), how can I know which device is currently used by WebRTC? (let's say I just want to display its label in the page)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20082861/1795426)

Comment: I saw it, but that allows me to select a device. What I want to know is what device has the user shared (most probably the default one).
Or another way to solve it (not as generic) will be to know which is the default device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MediaStreamTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack) (part of the MediaStream which you get from the getUserMedia success callback; use `stream.getTracks()` to get all tracks) has a `label` attribute which indicates the name of the device used.