# WebRTC Using back camera instead of front camera

Tags: camera, webrtc

I use simplewebrtc.com's webrtc solution (see https://simplewebrtc.com/demo.html).
When you join the room the front camera will be used. But i want to use back camera. There is info page (see "Selecting a microphone and camera" at https://simplewebrtc.com/notsosimple.html ) for that but i couldn't implement it. Could anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

first: In webrtc i think this should be handled in constraints passed to getUserMedia.

```
 { audio: true, video: { facingMode: { exact: "environment" } } }
```

you can log the lable of the using video device in browser's console:

```
  var videoTracks = localStream.getVideoTracks();
  if (videoTracks.length > 0) {
    trace('Using video device: ' + videoTracks[0].label);
  }
```

second: In browser's setting you can set default camera, e.g. in chrome go to **Settings>Advanced>Content Settings>Camera**

Comment: There is no option to select the camera in Chrome settings. I couldn't implement your code. Where should i add it?

Comment: The localStream variable in the code is the stream returned from getUserMedia.

Comment: Check this for browser settings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610945/how-to-choose-input-video-device-for-webrtc

Comment: and this http://support.doublerobotics.com/customer/portal/articles/1273966-how-to-change-the-camera-or-mic-chrome-uses